# Why is rax modified during stop-on-enter for `syscall`?

Tags: linux, gdb, x86-64, system-calls, cpu-registers

Run `gdb -q /bin/ls` and then `$ catch syscall` (not single stepping), the first syscall would be `brk`, which has sysno 12. However when I looked at the value of `rax` it's `0xffffffffffffffda`. Why is it so?

See the three "snapshots" below for details. The first one is taken on stop-on-enter for the syscall (see ptrace(2)), the second one is taken on stop-on-exit.

Here's snapshot during stop-on-enter.

```
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
RAX: 0xffffffffffffffda
RBX: 0x1
RCX: 0x7ffff7df0ec9 (<__brk+9>: cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000)
RDX: 0x4d ('M')
RSI: 0x43 ('C')
RDI: 0x0
RBP: 0x555555554040 --> 0x500000006
RSP: 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x7ffff7defc71 (<_dl_sysdep_start+913>: xor    eax,eax)
RIP: 0x7ffff7df0ec9 (<__brk+9>: cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000)
R8 : 0x16
R9 : 0x7ffff7df6665 ("MALLOC_CHECK_")
R10: 0x0
R11: 0x246
R12: 0x9 ('\t')
R13: 0x7ffff7dd7660 (<dl_main>: push   rbp)
R14: 0x1
R15: 0x1000
EFLAGS: 0x246 (carry PARITY adjust ZERO sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x7ffff7df0ec0 <__brk>:      mov    ecx,0xc
   0x7ffff7df0ec5 <__brk+5>:    mov    eax,ecx
   0x7ffff7df0ec7 <__brk+7>:    syscall 
=> 0x7ffff7df0ec9 <__brk+9>:    cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000
   0x7ffff7df0ecf <__brk+15>:   mov    rdx,rax
   0x7ffff7df0ed2 <__brk+18>:   ja     0x7ffff7df0ee8 <__brk+40>
   0x7ffff7df0ed4 <__brk+20>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x20d215],rax        # 0x7ffff7ffe0f0 <__curbrk>
   0x7ffff7df0edb <__brk+27>:   xor    eax,eax
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x7ffff7defc71 (<_dl_sysdep_start+913>:        xor    eax,eax)
0008| 0x7fffffffdde0 --> 0x100037f00000000
0016| 0x7fffffffdde8 --> 0x0
0024| 0x7fffffffddf0 --> 0xf8bfbff
0032| 0x7fffffffddf8 --> 0x7ffff7ffb000 (jg     0x7ffff7ffb047)
0040| 0x7fffffffde00 --> 0x7fffffffe249 --> 0x2ddd6da558be58c2
0048| 0x7fffffffde08 --> 0x101010100000064
0056| 0x7fffffffde10 --> 0x0
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall brk), 0x00007ffff7df0ec9 in __brk (addr=addr@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c:31
31      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c: No such file or directory.
gdb-peda$
```

Here's the one during stop-on-exit.

```
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
RAX: 0x555555776000 ('')
RBX: 0x1 
RCX: 0x7ffff7df0ec9 (<__brk+9>: cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000)
RDX: 0x4d ('M')
RSI: 0x43 ('C')
RDI: 0x0 
RBP: 0x555555554040 --> 0x500000006 
RSP: 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x7ffff7defc71 (<_dl_sysdep_start+913>: xor    eax,eax)
RIP: 0x7ffff7df0ec9 (<__brk+9>: cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000)
R8 : 0x16 
R9 : 0x7ffff7df6665 ("MALLOC_CHECK_")
R10: 0x0 
R11: 0x246 
R12: 0x9 ('\t')
R13: 0x7ffff7dd7660 (<dl_main>: push   rbp)
R14: 0x1 
R15: 0x1000
EFLAGS: 0x246 (carry PARITY adjust ZERO sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x7ffff7df0ec0 <__brk>:      mov    ecx,0xc
   0x7ffff7df0ec5 <__brk+5>:    mov    eax,ecx
   0x7ffff7df0ec7 <__brk+7>:    syscall 
=> 0x7ffff7df0ec9 <__brk+9>:    cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000
   0x7ffff7df0ecf <__brk+15>:   mov    rdx,rax
   0x7ffff7df0ed2 <__brk+18>:   ja     0x7ffff7df0ee8 <__brk+40>
   0x7ffff7df0ed4 <__brk+20>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x20d215],rax        # 0x7ffff7ffe0f0 <__curbrk>
   0x7ffff7df0edb <__brk+27>:   xor    eax,eax
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x7ffff7defc71 (<_dl_sysdep_start+913>:        xor    eax,eax)
0008| 0x7fffffffdde0 --> 0x100037f00000000 
0016| 0x7fffffffdde8 --> 0x0 
0024| 0x7fffffffddf0 --> 0xf8bfbff 
0032| 0x7fffffffddf8 --> 0x7ffff7ffb000 (jg     0x7ffff7ffb047)
0040| 0x7fffffffde00 --> 0x7fffffffe249 --> 0xbb35628be0b22313 
0048| 0x7fffffffde08 --> 0x101010100000064 
0056| 0x7fffffffde10 --> 0x0 
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Catchpoint 1 (returned from syscall brk), 0x00007ffff7df0ec9 in __brk (addr=addr@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c:31
31      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c
gdb-peda$
```

So `brk` returns `0x555555776000`, which is the current program break (since `RDI` was `0x0`, which will cause `brk` to return the current program break). And if I stop using breakpoint on the `syscall` instruction instead of catchpoint, I get the following snapshot, which shows that `RAX` was 12 for the syscall.

```
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
RAX: 0xc ('\x0c')
RBX: 0x1 
RCX: 0xc ('\x0c')
RDX: 0x4d ('M')
RSI: 0x43 ('C')
RDI: 0x0 
RBP: 0x555555554040 --> 0x500000006 
RSP: 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x7ffff7defc71 (<_dl_sysdep_start+913>: xor    eax,eax)
RIP: 0x7ffff7df0ec7 (<__brk+7>: syscall)
R8 : 0x16 
R9 : 0x7ffff7df6665 ("MALLOC_CHECK_")
R10: 0x0 
R11: 0x0 
R12: 0x9 ('\t')
R13: 0x7ffff7dd7660 (<dl_main>: push   rbp)
R14: 0x1 
R15: 0x1000
EFLAGS: 0x246 (carry PARITY adjust ZERO sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x7ffff7df0eba:      nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x7ffff7df0ec0 <__brk>:      mov    ecx,0xc
   0x7ffff7df0ec5 <__brk+5>:    mov    eax,ecx
=> 0x7ffff7df0ec7 <__brk+7>:    syscall 
   0x7ffff7df0ec9 <__brk+9>:    cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff000
   0x7ffff7df0ecf <__brk+15>:   mov    rdx,rax
   0x7ffff7df0ed2 <__brk+18>:   ja     0x7ffff7df0ee8 <__brk+40>
   0x7ffff7df0ed4 <__brk+20>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x20d215],rax        # 0x7ffff7ffe0f0 <__curbrk>
No argument
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x7ffff7defc71 (<_dl_sysdep_start+913>:        xor    eax,eax)
0008| 0x7fffffffdde0 --> 0x100037f00000000 
0016| 0x7fffffffdde8 --> 0x0 
0024| 0x7fffffffddf0 --> 0xf8bfbff 
0032| 0x7fffffffddf8 --> 0x7ffff7ffb000 (jg     0x7ffff7ffb047)
0040| 0x7fffffffde00 --> 0x7fffffffe249 --> 0xb0d23aa8f5c20e1 
0048| 0x7fffffffde08 --> 0x101010100000064 
0056| 0x7fffffffde10 --> 0x0 
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7df0ec7 in __brk (addr=addr@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c:31
31      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c: No such file or directory.
gdb-peda$
```

In one sentence, `RAX` went `0xc` -> `0xffffffffffffffda` -> `0x555555776000`.

Comment: Um, the arrow points to the instruction after the syscall. You're looking the syscall's return value.

Comment: I thought so, but it seems it's really not the case. Gdb catches syscalls and provides an stop-on-enter and stop-on-exit (ptrace(2) terms). The return value can be seen in the snapshot for stop-on-exit. What I am more interested in is the value shown in stop-on-enter.

Comment: Why do you say that gdb is showing the wrong value for RIP? `0x7ffff7df0ec9` seems legit.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry for the confusion, hopefully I clarified the question now.

Comment: After some research, here's the instruction that causes the value `0xffffffffffffffda`, or `-38` or `-ENOSYS`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11-tree/source/arch/x86_64/kernel/entry.S#L243. Hopefully someone can clarify why this value is used.

Comment: That's weird; `strace /bin/ls` doesn't show it making any system calls that return -ENOSYS, and rax=12 / syscall is `sys_brk` which will never return `-ENOSYS`.  Could GDB have somehow corrupted RAX before entering the kernel?  I assume you're on GNU/Linux based on the call numbers, ptrace, and seeing glibc's `MALLOC_CHECK_` symbol name, but it would be good if you add more info about software versions (GDB and kernel) to your question, and a distro name / version.

Comment: I think what's going on is that the kernel by default sets `rax` to `-ENOSYS` at the start of syscall processing, so that if the call is not supported, the error code is already in place. If the call is supported, then the syscall handler updates `rax` to the actual return value. But it means that if you break in while the syscall handler is running, you see the temporary `-ENOSYS` value.